# Import google-java-format from Eclipse to VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, eclipse-plugin, google-java-format

I have an archive plugin for Eclipse that contains an personalized google-java-format implementation, I want to import this to VSCode editor, is it possible to this?I found how to do this with xml files but not with archives (a jar containing *.class files).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Could you get the xml profile in your mentioned plugin? If yes, make sure you have installed [Java extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) first, VSCode can use a specified Eclipse xml profile as it's formatter profile.

You can check the setting `java.format.settings.url`. When it's specified, the given formatter profile will be used in VSCode Java formatting.

Another way to use it is to trigger command `Java: Open Java formatter settings`, and it will help you generate a default formatter profile, you can change the content to what you want.

Comment: In the plugin jar file I only have one xml on the root, it does not contains much:


`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<profiles version="1"/>`

I think this is not enough for visual studio code to apply the formatter, no?

Comment: How does eclipse apply your plugin? Can you export the profile manually?

Comment: No I cannot import it manually, eclipse just uses the jar archive to apply the plugin

Comment: I just checked the usage of the google-java-format plugin. After drop in the plugin, you can get a new profile called `google-java-format` in `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`, right? In this page you can export the active profile or setting as a xml file.

Answer (score 0):

To directly set "`Google Java Style`" as "`Java's format`" on `VSCode`, please:

1.Install "`Extension Pack for Java`".

e.g: "`Extension Pack for Java v0.9.1`" + "`Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat v0.64.1`" for "`Java1.8`".

Making sure COMPILING, RUNNING and DEBUGGING are successful before "`Next Step`"!

2.Set the default formatter of `Java` into "`RedHat`".

2.1Using hotKeyMap to open the `Settings` of `VSCode`, e.g: `Ctrl/Cmd` + `,`

( or Click the logo of `VSCode` "`Code`" button and choose "`Preference`" menu and then click "`Setting`")

2.2Type "`javahome`" in the "`Search settings`" space, then click "`Edit in settings.json`",

2.3Adding the below code into your "`settings.json`",

```
"java.format.settings.url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml",
"java.format.settings.profile": "GoogleStyle",
"java.format.settings.imports.onDemand": false,
"java.format.settings.imports.regexp": "^[a-z.]*",
"[java]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java",
    "editor.tabSize": 2
}
```

2.4Then restart the "`VSCode`", Using `shift` + `alt/option` + `f` to automatic "`Java's format`" into "`Google Java Style`".

END!